# Hyperledger Fabric: How to setup ICA on a different host?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we are trying to generalize [fabric-ca](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/fabric-ca) sample to run on multiple hosts. as is it runs on a single host and thus is of no use in a real-world scenario.

The problem we are facing is this: we spin up the Root CA on host 1. Then when we spin up the ICA on host 2, we need to provide it the cert of root CA in FABRIC_CA_SERVER_INTERMEDIATE_TLS_CERTFILES variable. In the sample this is done by mounting a shared volume which is a hack that works if containers are on single host.

in [env.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/scripts/env.sh#L39)

```
# The volume mount to share data between containers
DATA=data
```

in [start-root-ca.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/scripts/start-root-ca.sh#L14)

```
# Copy the root CA's signing certificate to the data directory to be used by others
cp $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/ca-cert.pem $TARGET_CERTFILE
```

But if the containers are on different hosts, then how can ICA get the cert of Root CA? `fabric-ca-client getcacert` is no no use because it runs into chicken and egg problem - to communicate with Root CA, we need its cert to be in list of trusted certificates.

How can we solve this issue?

we looked into how to create a shared volume across docker hosts over [here](https://jaxenter.com/how-to-share-docker-volumes-across-hosts-119602.html):

1. It looks very complicated and more work than what we signed up for
2. we really don't want to setup a shared volume as it introduces chances of bugs (one person overwrites file of another) and unwanted coupling.

The other option is to be able to copy file (the root ca cert in our case) from one container on host 1 (the root CA) to another container on host 2 (the ICA). This also does not seem straightforward [ref](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/copying-data-between-docker-containers-26890935da3f). we were really hoping for a simple clean solution and surprised not to find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intermediate CA is trying to connect to a root CA server with TLS enabled, then yes you will need to get the root CA server's TLS certificate file out of band. Other than that you really have no way of establishing a secure connection.

Another option you could go with is to do all network bootstrapping without TLS and get all the appropriate chain files, and then enable TLS on all the servers.

Comment: re: option 2, do we have to restart the servers to enable TLS? If we have to restart, it invalidates the previous certs. If not, how can we enable TLS? could you provide the details? thanks

Comment: To enable TLS, you will have to restart the servers. But, not sure why it would invalidate the previous certs. Just make sure you don't delete the CA server's existing cert and key and make sure you specify the cert and key when you start the server again and no certificates should become invalid.